# How can I getpixel and setpixel from an Image as HSB instead of RGB?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any fast way, or do I have to convert manually them? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(1, 2, 3);
float h, s, b;
h = c.GetHue();
s = c.GetSaturation();
b = c.GetBrightness();
```

Comment: thanks. In this way, is there any fast way to convert back to RGB?

Comment: See SuperOli's answer for the ColorFromHSBFunction

Comment: that method didnt work.. All goes black =x. But I may search for another

Comment: I have done this but I'm not able to access that piece of code. Maybe you can write your own function based on this article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB
From HSV is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

You could use extensions methods like so:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Tuple<float, float, float> GetPixelHSB(this Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y)
    {
        Color c = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
        float h, s, b;
        h = c.GetHue();
        s = c.GetSaturation();
        b = c.GetBrightness();

        return Tuple.Create<float, float, float>(h, s, b);
    }

    public static void SetPixelHSB(this Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, Tuple<float, float, float> hsb)
    {
        bitmap.SetPixelHSB(x, y, hsb.Item1, hsb.Item2, hsb.Item3);
    }

    public static void SetPixelHSB(this Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, float h, float s, float b)
    {
        Color c = ColorFromHSBFunction(h, s, b);
        bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, c);
    }
}
```

A `ColorFromHSBFunction` can be found [here](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=846).

Comment: Don't forget that GetSaturation() and GetBrightness() returns the value as a float (ranging from 0.0f to 1.0f). The link to the ColorFromHSBFunction that I gave you treats these values as ints from 0 to 100. You would need to tweak the function to make it work.

Comment: I tried  that. But maybe my code to access that method is wrong. Thanks.